# Second fundamental long exact sequence of Koszul Homology

Tags: commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I'm currently reading the book *Monomial Ideals* by Herzog and Hibi.

More precisely, in the Appendix A.3 the Koszul complex is studied. I would like to get some clarifications.

The authors consider $R$ a commutative ring (with unit), and
\begin{align}
{\bf f}&=f_1,\dots,f_{m-1},f_m,\\
{\bf g}&=f_1,\dots,f_{m-1},
\end{align}
be sequences of elements of $R$. Let $M$ be an $R$-module, and let $K_i({\bf f};M)$, $H_i({\bf f};M)$ be the $i$-th Koszul module and the $i$-th homology module of the Koszul complex of $M$ attached to ${\bf f}$.

**Theorem A.3.3.** claims that there is a long exact sequence:

\begin{aligned}
0 \rightarrow H_{m}(\mathbf{f} ;&M) \rightarrow H_{m-1}(\mathbf{g} ; M) \rightarrow H_{m-1}(\mathbf{g} ; M) \rightarrow H_{m-1}(\mathbf{f} ; M) \rightarrow \cdots \\
\cdots & \rightarrow H_{i}(\mathbf{f} ; M) \rightarrow H_{i-1}(\mathbf{g} ; M) \rightarrow H_{i-1}(\mathbf{g} ; M) \rightarrow H_{i-1}(\mathbf{f} ; M) \rightarrow \cdots \\
\cdots & \cdots H_{1}(\mathbf{f} ; M) \rightarrow H_{0}(\mathbf{g} ; M) \rightarrow H_{0}(\mathbf{g} ; M) \rightarrow H_{0}(\mathbf{f} ; M) \rightarrow 0,
\end{aligned}
where $H_i({\bf g};M)\rightarrow H_i({\bf g};M)$ is multiplication by $\pm f_m$.

I would like an explicit description of the other maps. I know that the map $\alpha_i:H_i({\bf f};M)\rightarrow H_{i-1}({\bf g};M)$ act as follows: if $a=a_0+a_1\wedge e_m$ is a cycle of $K_i({\bf f};M)$, with $a_i\in K_i({\bf g};M)$ and $a_1\in K_{i-1}({\bf g};M)$, then $\alpha_i([a])=[a_1]$, where $[-]$ denotes the homology class.

**My question is** how is defined the map $\beta_i:H_i({\bf g};M)\rightarrow H_i({\bf f};M)$? Does it simply sends $[a]$ to the corresponding homology class of $H_i({\bf f};M)$? If so, what is the kernel of this map?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is indeed as you describe.  There is an inclusion of complexes (in fact, an inclusion of differential-graded algebras) which sends $a$ to $a+0e_m$ where $e_m$ is the exterior variable satisfying $\partial e_m =f_m.$  Avramov's book "infinite free resolutions" describes the general case (for the adjunction of an exterior variable, in any odd degree, to an differential-graded algebra), see remark 6.1.5.  I know this doesn't answer all of your questions (I don't have an explicit description of the kernel) but I hope that helps get you started!